# Mongodb Find with reserved name

Tags: mongodb

I need to do find() command on mongodb in collection with name "group" but "group" apparently is a reserved name, so.. I need select it lines with other command. How I can do find() in this case?

My tests:

```
> db['group'].find()
Tue Nov  3 09:30:22.132 TypeError: Object function ( parmsObj ){
var ret = this.runCommand( { "group" : this._groupFixParms( parmsObj ) } );
  if ( ! ret.ok ){
      throw "group command failed: " + tojson( ret );
  }
  return ret.retval;
} has no method 'find'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
db.getCollection("group").find()
```

In your case, the **[`db.getCollection()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/#db.getCollection)** method is quite useful for a collection whose name might interact with the shell itself, such names that begin with **`_`** or that mirror the database commands like **[`group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/group/#dbcmd.group)** or **[`count`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/count/#dbcmd.count)**.

Comment: @balancin No worries, happy to help :)